# passing a string from one form to another in C# visual studios

Tags: c#, winforms

A similar question has been asked here previously, but mine is a little bit different.

So in this situation, in my form 1 class, I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String hello;
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnFindMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hello = "hi";


        frm2.myProperty = hello;
        frm2.Show();

    }
```

}

Now, in my Form2 class, I have:

```
public String myProperty { get; set; }
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(myProperty);

    }
```

So basically, myProperty returns as null. However if I had written 
String hello = "hi"; 
in the Form1 class, it would have returned as "hi".

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Pass in the Form2 Constructor

Comment: The issue is that the messagebox pops up as blank. I assume this is because what's being passed is just 

"String myProperty;"

Comment: Based on the code you post it should work fine - so something else is either setting `hello` to null in `Form1` or setting `myProperty` to null in `Form2`.  I would run it in the debugger, watching those variables and see when they change.

Comment: Rebuild your solution please and try again.